# Find lower case letter not followed by period

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need to find to find any instance of a comma followed by a line break then a lower case letter that is not immediately followed by a period. 
I tried `(,)\r\n([a-z][^\.])`, which didn't work.
My goal is to replace the line breaks with a space using `$1 $2` (assuming there would still be capturing groups).

Comment: What language / tool / library are you using?

Comment: I'm using the find and replace tool in a .txt file in Notepad++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, check if `Match case` option is on. It must be on, or your patterns will be case insensitive by default, unless you use `(?-i)` or `(?-i:...)`.

Then, to match a linebreak, you may use `\R` and to assert the absence of a dot on the right, you may use a negative lookahead, `(?!\.)`.

Hence, you may use

```
(?-i),\R([a-z])(?!\.)
```

and replace with `,$1`.

**Details**

- `(?-i)` - turn on case sensitivity
- `,` - match a comma
- `\R` - a line break sequence
- `([a-z])` - Group 1: a lowercase ASCII letter
- `(?!\.)` - no dot is allowed immediately to the right of the current location.